# Out of range value for column 'release_d' at row 2

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

First time to ask a question. Will do my best to follow the tips:

```
UPDATE albums  
SET release_d = 1800  
WHERE release_d < 1980;
```

or

```
UPDATE albums  
SET release_d = '1800'         
WHERE release_d <= '1980';
```

I receive the error exactly as this: 
Out of range value for column `'release_d'` at row 2 
I just don't see it. Using Sequel Pro, `MySQL 5`.

Trying to change the year of the release date.
The possible answers found were far too complex for me.
Thanks for the kindness.

Comment: Show the ddl and sample data

Comment: Change your type in the database of release_d to varchar and then be sure to quote the strings.

Comment: @MrTechie: please refrain from such advice without learning details about database structure first. This could easily lead to data loss for OP.

Comment: If you reference any "Out of range" on the internet it will always come back to the type

Comment: Thanks MrTechie, your advice helped.

Comment: Thanks Jens and xsami, I will know how to better ask a question with tables next time.